Problem with animating a character
I just started animating this character, the only problem is that when I rotate the arm, the whole part rotates, (i dont know how to explain it well) and so I can't just rotate the arm.


Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

It looks like you are trying to animate the arm by keyframes. Keyframes are set for the complete object, you cannot animate only parts of the mesh by setting keyframes in Edit Mode. To only animate the arm it must be either a separate object or needs parenting to an armature with weight painting, which is best to be learned by watching tutorials on armature and rigging etc., as it is a complex topic not to be solved in a single quick answer if you have never heard anything about it.
